# how to rotate a kinematic body in clockwise and anti clockwise in box2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Can any one suggest me or give idea about this scenario

1. I am having a dynamic bodies(balls)
2. Also having kinematic bodies(wooden blocks which is on circular shape)

When a ball hits the wooden block the wooden block should rotate a its own center with some angle and should stop after couple of seconds(0.2 ms).

When the ball hits the right side of the block it should rotate in clockwise direstion... and when the ball hits the wooden block in left side it should rotate in  anti clockwise direction.

I tried like this for the kinematic body(wooden block) when it get contact with the ball.

```
blockBody->SetAngularVelocity( -60 * DEGTORAD );
```

but the wooden  block keep on rotating in clockwise direction.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Thanks all

Comment: Yes, because a negative angle means clockwise rotation in Box2D. How about setting it to a positive value? Or are you saying that no matter what value you set it always rotates clockwise?

Comment: I mean when a dynamic body hits right side of the kinematic body it(kinematic body) should rotate in clockwise, if it hits left side of the  kinematic body its should rotate in anti clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should not handle and solve collision by yourself, but rather you should set up the different weight/size and friction for each object, and have box2d handle the collision for you.

Comment: you mean that I have to reduce the density and friction of the kinematic body?? the automatic collision is done. the thing is when the ball hits the kinematic body to the right the kinematic body should rotate along clockwise if the hit is on left it should rotate along anti clockwise with some angle. This part of rotation how can I achieve please suggest...